# PSR-4 autoloading not working - cannot find class

Tags: php, autoload, psr-4

I'm trying to split up a long file into smaller chunks, so I created an `src` folder, and am trying to reference it from the main `Extension.php` file (which loads and works fine, by the way).

So, I add the `src` folder to the psr-4 autoloading array:

```
"psr-4": {
        "Bolt\\Extension\\AndyJessop\\SurveyMonkey\\": [
            "",
            "src/"
        ]
    }
```

I create the `Test.php` file inside `src`:

```
<?php

namespace Bolt\Extension\AndyJessop\SurveyMonkey;

class Test
{
    public function test() {
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

In the `Extension.php` file (which is under the same namespace), I have this function that is called:

```
use Bolt\Extension\AndyJessop\SurveyMonkey\Test;

public function testing(){
    return Test::test();
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Class 'Bolt\Extension\AndyJessop\SurveyMonkey\Test' not found
File: extensions/local/andyjessop/surveymonkey/Extension.php
```

Comment: If you haven't already, try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I still get `Class 'Bolt\Extension\AndyJessop\SurveyMonkey\Test' not found`

Answer (score 2):

First, either run `composer update` or `composer dump-autoload` to generate the autoload system.

Next, make sure that you include (require_once is preferable) the autoload at the top of your entrypoint(s):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

N.B.: if you have PHP 5.3 or lower, replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`.